# Angular 7 : Is it possible to extend routes of a component in a child component?

Tags: angular, routes, components, angular7

I would like to create a component looking like a button which redirects to his own route when clicked.

My component module :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        children: [
          {
            path: 'child',
            component: MyChildComponent
          }
        ],
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [...],
  declarations: [MyComponent, MyChildComponent],
  exports: [MyComponent, RouterModule]
})
export class MyComponentModule { }
...
```

My component controller :

```
export class MyComponent {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  onClick() {
    this.router.navigate(['child'], { relativeTo: this.route })
  }
}
```

Now if I use MyComponent on an other component, an error is thrown on click:

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'parentPath.../child'
```

I already tried this on MyComponent's routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'child',
    component: MyComponent
  }
]
```

It works but I can't launch again MyChildComponent (null is returned from the navigate function) and navigate function doesn't match the route 'child' if I use the component on my root app.

So, is it possible to extend the rout mapping of a component on a child component?

Comment: Did you add the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your parent template?

Comment: What do you mean by parent ? In MyComponent template or MyComponent' parent template ?

Comment: Hope this link will help you : https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/child_routes.html